# How to write a javascript test using JEST framework for validating promise

Tags: javascript, jestjs, promise

I am completely new to JEST framework, and I want to know how I can write a testcase to validate a function that returns a promise.

Here's the code for which I want to write a testcase-

```
import AwPromiseService from 'js/awPromiseService';

export const getRejectionPromise = function( err ) {
    let deferred = AwPromiseService.instance.defer();
    deferred.reject( err );
    return deferred.promise;
};

export const getResolvePromise = function(){
    let deferred = AwPromiseService.instance.defer();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I created a test file and tried to write a test as below but, didn't succeed.

```
import AwPromiseService from 'js/awPromiseService';

// Mock your promise library
jest.mock('js/awPromiseService', () => {
    return {
        instance: {
            defer: jest.fn()
        }
    };
});

describe( 'Testing adminPreferenceUserUtil', function() {
    afterEach( function() {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    } );

    it('validate getRejectionPromise should return a rejected promise', async () => {
        const error = new Error('Test error');
        const deferredMock = { reject: jest.fn() };

        AwPromiseService.instance.defer.mockReturnValue(deferredMock);

        const promise = getRejectionPromise(error);

        expect(AwPromiseService.instance.defer).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(deferredMock.reject).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);

        await expect(promise).rejects.toBe(error);
    });

    // Similarly tried for other function "getResolvePromise()" 
});
```

Can anyone please help me to understand how I can write a working testcase for my code?